# Using Case in a Where Clause for Dates

Tags: sql, t-sql

I currently have this `WHERE` clause that includes the following parameters.

```
WHERE 
    Project ID=110
    AND ((CAST(saa.Date AS DATE) >= '09/24/2014' AND CAST(saa.Date AS DATE) <= '09/24/2014') OR saa.Date IS NULL))
```

The tricky part here is that the `saa.Date is NULL` section is going to pull up ALL `Null` Values in all dates (which is excessive) I only want to use the following Date Range for the `Null` Values

```
(
        (CAST(sa.StartDateTime AS DATE) >= '09/24/2014' AND CAST(sa.StartDateTime AS DATE) <= '09/24/2014')
        OR
        (CAST(sa.EndDateTime AS DATE) >= '09/24/2014' AND CAST(sa.EndDateTime AS DATE) <= '09/24/2014')
)
```

So I'm trying to figure out how I can create a `CASE` statement that would work that would be something like IF saa.Date is NULL Then [Use Date Range Parameters above]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll base my answer in @AHiggins's but adding performance an readability

-- [sergability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)

-- avoiding `cast`

-- [using `between`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-es/library/ms187922.aspx)

```
WHERE 
    ProjectID=110 AND 
     (
      (
        saa.Date between '09/24/2014 00:00:00.000' AND '09/24/2014 23:59:59.999'
      ) OR 
      (
        saa.Date IS NULL AND
         (
            sa.StartDateTime between '09/24/2014 00:00:00.000' AND  '09/24/2014 23:59:59.999'
         ) OR
         (
            sa.EndDateTime between  '09/24/2014 00:00:00.000' AND '09/24/2014 23:59:59.999'
         )
      )
     )
```

Make sure you have indexes on thos date columns

Comment: A few hours ago, I received a down votes for not mention the surce which inspired my answer!!! :)

Comment: Weirdly enough this only produces the non-null values

Comment: @StayPuft could you add schema, data sample and actual query on SQLFidle?

Comment: Actually did my own fiddling around and worked! Thanks for the follow up though

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading it right, you should be able to do this with Boolean logic and a few million parentheses:

EDIT: noticed in the comments on @horaciux's answer that there's an issue, realized we actually need a couple more parentheses.  I've borrowed back the borrowed code and added the extras below.

```
WHERE 
    ProjectID=110 AND 
     (
      (
        saa.Date between '09/24/2014 00:00:00.000' AND '09/24/2014 23:59:59.999'
      ) OR 
      (
        saa.Date IS NULL AND
         ( -- need to wrap the next two conditions in a single set of parentheses
          (
            sa.StartDateTime between '09/24/2014 00:00:00.000' AND  '09/24/2014 23:59:59.999'
          ) OR
          (
            sa.EndDateTime between  '09/24/2014 00:00:00.000' AND '09/24/2014 23:59:59.999'
          )
         )
      )
     )
```

Comment: StayPuft, I think there's still one set of missing parentheses: I've borrowed back the code @horaciux improved and edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You do know that

```
    >= '09/24/2014' 
AND <= '09/24/2014'
```

is the same as 
         = '09/24/2014'

```
where ProjectID=110 
  AND CAST(saa.Date AS DATE) = '09/24/2014' 
   OR (
        saa.Date IS NULL 
        AND
            ( 
              CAST(sa.StartDateTime AS DATE) = '09/24/2014'
              OR
              CAST(sa.EndDateTime AS DATE)   = '09/24/2014' 
            )              
      )
```

This is more efficient than a cast:

```
DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, COL),0)
```

But the answer from Horaciux is even more efficient

Comment: thanks for mention that. It feels good when it came from high reputation users.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(
        (CAST(ISNULL(sa.StartDateTime, '09/24/2014') AS DATE) >= '09/24/2014' AND CAST(ISNULL(saa.StartDateTime, '09/24/2014') AS DATE) <= '09/24/2014')
)
```